# using pandas date_range with an unspecified end date

Tags: python, pandas, date-range

Is there a typical way to use pandas date_range to specify an open-ended period of time?

For example, a contract where the end date is determined by some event, so only the start date is known when the agreement is created.

** UPDATE **

I wound up flagging an unspecified end date like so

```
pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp.now(), freq="N", periods=1)
```

Comment: what are you hoping for? ... date range is a start and stop ... are you hoping for infinite periods?

Comment: @JoranBeasley. Yes, is date_range not the right object to do that?

Comment: Can you provide minimal code to demonstrate a use case?

Comment: What I think in this scenario is to state the maximum allowed date (IE:1/1/2199) and then if a condition happens re state it.

Comment: But what will OP do with this date range?

Comment: @Sgdva. that was my original thought also; not knowing the object well I thought there might be a way to do this and minimize or eliminate the generation of periods. It looks like the largest period is Annual, so 198 periods would be generated.

Comment: You need to specify 3 of the parameters. It looks like you could use `pd.date_range(start='2023-07-18', periods=198, freq='A')`